# In Yolov5, How Can we hide confidence levels on predicted image using model=torch.hub.load() and results=model(img)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, annotations, yolo, yolov5

while using `python detect.py`, we can hide the confidence level using flag `--hide-conf`

My question is, Can we do the same while using `model=torch.hub.load()` and then `results=model(img)`. Once we write `results.show()`, I want only boxes with name of the classes on the image and want to hide confidence scores.

I have tried using,

```
model_damage_annot.conf=0.4
model_damage_annot.iou=0.15
model_damage_annot.max_det=20
```

This works but `model_damage_annot.hide_conf=True` doesn't work. What is the correct way to do it?

The resulting pictures are showing confidence scores and I want to hide them. Please guide me

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the detect.py files and added the params just like yours but none of them worked for me. but since, the confidence score and their bounding boxes (xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin) can be extracted I stored them in a variable then drawed the bounding boxes on my own. you can try out my code.

```
results = model(img)  
    
bboxes = results.pred[0][:, :4] 

total_area_covered = 0
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 0, 0, 0, 0

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
for bbox in bboxes:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox.int().tolist()
    
    for i in range(x1, x2, 4):
        draw.line([(i, y1), (i + 2, y1)], fill="black", width=3)
        draw.line([(i, y2), (i + 2, y2)], fill="black", width=3)
    for i in range(y1, y2, 4):
        draw.line([(x1, i), (x1, i + 2)], fill="black", width=3)
        draw.line([(x2, i), (x2, i + 2)], fill="black", width=3)
    
    total_area_covered += (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)

img.save(output_path)
```